# error in git trying to push after a rebase

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Disclaimer: I'm sort of a git and version control newb.

At work we're thinking about using git to manage our customizations to a COTS product we purchased. I'm having a little bit of a hard time figuring out the best way to approach this.

My idea was that we would have three perm branches:

- master (the default vendor files)
- gold (branch of master, our added stuff + customized vendor files, this is the gold source)
- development (branch of gold, stuff being developed, duh!)

The workflow would go something like:

- for vendor patches: branch master, update files, merge back into master, rebase gold merging our customizations back into the vendors updated files
- for hotfixes (our code): branch gold, fix code, merge back into gold, rebase development
- for new features (our code): branch dev, merge back in when ready, merge into gold when we are doing a release

So in my testing, I mostly like how it's working, commit history looks good, flow seems ok, but the big problem i think i have is that it requires me to force push after the rebase. for example:

```
git checkout development
git checkout -b feat-myfeature
*do my thing, commit changes*
git checkout development
git merge feat-myfeature
git push

git checkout gold
git merge development
git push

git checkout master
git checkout -b patch-xxxxx
*update the vendor files, do commits*
git checkout master
git merge patch-xxxxx

git checkout gold
git rebase master
*fix conflicts, adding back our customizations*
git add .
git rebase --continue
git push (error!)
```

At this point git tells me I have a divergent history and i either must pull and de-conflict the exact same things i just de-conflicted with the rebase or a force push works too...I think the force push is going to cause me all sorts of headaches that I'm not even aware of and the fact that a pull forces me to fix the same conflicts again makes me think i've make a mistake with my plan somewhere along the way.

Can you guys offer any suggestions to improve this flow?

edit: formatting

Answer (score 0):

You cannot push once your branches have diverged. The only time you can push changes to the server is when your branch is *ahead* of the remote branch and a simple [fast-forward](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) merge can be performed.

To push your rebased branch you need to *force* push, which *overwrites* the remote state of the branch. This will break things badly for anybody else who is using your branch, so warn them before you do it.

```
git push -f
```